# Ajax Call using jsonp for calling rest webservice from other domain

Tags: html

How I use the jsonp when call to rest webservice  from different domain.becouse my simple json does not working for rest webservice.how can i call rest webservice for ajax call.i use both jsonp and javascript for that.server responce i seen on only browser in firebug  but how to show it on my application

my JS code.

function callService() {
            $.ajax({
                type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                url: varUrl, // Location of the service
                data: varData, //Data sent to server
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
                dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
                processdata: varProcessData, //True or False
                success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
                    alert("Server Responce Successfully!..");
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert('error ' + msg.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function countryProvinceWCFJSONMulti() {

```
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'JSON';
        script.src = "http://192.168.15.213/myservice/Service.svc/GetEvents";
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        head.appendChild(script);
        varType = "GET";           
        varData = '{"username": "' + "Suhasusername" + '","password": "' + "suhaspassword" + '"}';
        varContentType = "application/JSONP; charset=utf-8";
        varDataType = "JSONP";
        varProcessData = true;
        callService();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the same-origin policy isn't an issue, your code should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: url,
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         success: function (data) {
               alert("Server Response Successful!..");
        }
    });
```

[Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) that talks about circumventing the same-origin policy

Comment: My webservice is in different location and client is at differnt location i means IP address so then how i use that.